# adding weight list to already created edgelist from pandas dataframe and display the weight as a edge label in graph

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx, graph-visualization

I have my data in pandas dataframe,   it has source, target , weight.

> H=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(links,source='source',target='target')

used this to create my edge list, this doesnt have an option to add weights, i have also kept my data  in different forms apart from pd.DataFrame

> edges_df={'source':links['source'],
> 'target':links['target'],
> 'weights':links['value']}
> edges_source=links['source']
> edges_target=links['target']
> weights=links['value']

same thing but different structure , i tried using nx.set_edge_attribute but it gave an error along the lines of not iterable/hashable , not in the G[u][v][w]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple thing would be to use the `edge_attr` parameter when creating your graph like below.

```
H=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(links,source='source',target='target',edge_attr='weight')
```

If you already created the graph and want to add the attributes after the fact, you can use

```
for e in g.edges:
    g.edges[e]['weight'] = df.loc[(df.source == e[0]) & (df.target == e[1]),'weight'].values[0] #use .value[0] to ensure you get the value, not an array or series
```

Comment: i tried the first one and it worked ! how would i plot those weights as edge labels?? thanks xx

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark as answered for others who have the same question.

To plot the graph with the edge weights you can use
`nx.draw_networkx(g,pos) # draw the graph`
`nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g,pos,edge_labels={(u,v):w for u,v,w in g.edges(data='weight')}) # add edge weights as labels`
Where `pos` is a dict of node locations found using one of the `*_layout` functions

Comment: it gives an error, NoneType' object is not subscriptable its the edge_labels giving an error. could you tell me what does{(u,v):w for u,v,w in g.edges(data='weight') do?

Comment: Hmm... The line `{(u,v):w for...}` should make a dictionary with the edge as the keys and the weight as the value. If you're getting an error about a NoneType, it sounds like the weights didn't actually get added to your graph. What output do you get when you run `g.edges(data='weight')` this should give something similar to a list of tuples of form (head, tail, weight) for each edge. If it gives (head, tail, None), then the weights aren't actually stored in the graph.

Comment: i did the edge_labels={(u,v.} separately and it gave all the values as needed , but while adding it to nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(..) is when it gives an error   in draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels, label_pos, font_size, font_color, font_family, font_weight, alpha, bbox, ax, rotate, **kwds)
     text_items = {}
    for (n1, n2), label in labels.items():
     (x1, y1) = pos[n1]
             (x2, y2) = pos[n2]
           (x, y) = (x1 * label_pos + x2 * (1.0 - label_pos),
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I can't tell what's going on based on what you've provided. It would be helpful to see the full line of code when you call `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64709312/error-displaying-edge-labels-from-pandas-dataframe-networkx

Comment: heres  a better look.